# Approximation of harmonic function

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-analysis, linear-pde

For harmonic function $u\in C^2(B_r(0))\cap C(\overline B_r(0)),$ is there a sequence of harmonic functions $u_n\in C^2(B_r(0))\cap C^1(\overline B_r(0))$ such that $u_n \to u$ in $C(\overline B_r(0))$? Here $ B_r(0)$ is an open ball centered at $0$ with radius $r$.

I would be grateful if you give any comment for this question.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you can actually make this quite explicit using the tools of potential theory: given $f \in C(\partial B_r)$, take $f_n \in C^\infty(\partial B_r)$ with $f_n \to f$ uniformly, and consider the associated Dirichlet problems for $f_n$ and $f$.

Comment: @Ian  Thanks for your answer, but my question is related to harmonic functions. I don’t understand your answer for my question.

Comment: When I say "the associated Dirichlet problems for $f_n$ and $f$" I mean the problems of finding harmonic $u_n,u$ with $u_n=f_n,u=f$ on the boundary.

Comment: Maximum principle can be used for the rest of proof. Am I right?

Comment: Yep, $\| u_n - u \|_{L^\infty} \leq \| f_n - f \|_{L^\infty}$.

Comment: @lan Thanks again! By the way, how can we guarantee the existence of $f_n$ satisfying the property you wrote above?

Comment: Mollifiers, essentially, though there are some geometric technicalities about mollification on the boundary rather than inside the domain (which are *also* a major topic of potential theory). The ball is more or less the easiest domain to handle these technicalities in.

Comment: @Ian  Would you give any reference for it?

Comment: Just that you can probably find in Evans PDE somewhere (look for "straightening the boundary"). But if you are interested in potential theory in general, I recommend Armitage and Gardiner.